# Fill Miss Years in Panel Data

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, panel-data

I have what I believe is a very simple problem but I have been unable to find any solution to it on the internet. I am trying to clean panel data and I have a dataset where the observations have been recorded in irregular time steps. The entity is states and the unit of time is in years. I would like to fill in the missing years for each state, fill the new rows with `NA`.

Here is part of the data frame:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(State = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alaska", 
"Alaska", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"Arkansas", "California", "California", "California", "California", 
"California", "California", "Colorado", "Colorado", "Colorado", 
"Colorado", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Connecticut", "Connecticut", 
"Connecticut", "Connecticut", "Connecticut", "Connecticut", "Delaware", 
"Delaware", "District of Columbia", "District of Columbia", "District of Columbia", 
"Florida", "Florida", "Florida", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", 
"Hawaii", "Hawaii", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Idaho", "Idaho", "Idaho", 
"Illinois", "Illinois", "Illinois", "Illinois", "Illinois", "Indiana", 
"Indiana", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kansas", "Kentucky", 
"Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Louisiana", "Louisiana", 
"Maine", "Maine", "Maine", "Maine", "Maine", "Maryland", "Maryland", 
"Maryland", "Maryland", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Massachusetts", 
"Massachusetts", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Michigan", "Michigan", 
"Minnesota", "Minnesota", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Mississippi", 
"Mississippi", "Missouri", "Missouri", "Montana", "Montana", 
"Nebraska", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "Nevada", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", 
"New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Jersey", "New Jersey", "New Jersey", 
"New Mexico", "New Mexico", "New Mexico", "New Mexico", "New Mexico", 
"New Mexico", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Carolina", "North Carolina", 
"North Carolina", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "North Dakota", 
"North Dakota", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", 
"Oklahoma", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Oregon", "Oregon", "Oregon", 
"Pennsylvania", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "Rhode Island", 
"Rhode Island", "Rhode Island", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", 
"South Carolina", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Tennessee", "Tennessee", "Tennessee", "Tennessee", 
"Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Utah", "Utah", "Utah", "Utah", "Vermont", 
"Vermont", "Vermont", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia", 
"Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Washington", "Washington", 
"Washington", "Washington", "West Virginia", "West Virginia", 
"West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", 
"Wisconsin", "Wyoming", "Wyoming"), Year = c(2001, 2015, 2016, 
2001, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2015, 2001, 2008, 2011, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2001, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2003, 2012, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2014, 2001, 2013, 2017, 2001, 2015, 
2016, 2001, 2014, 2017, 2001, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2001, 2010, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2015, 2016, 2001, 2016, 2001, 
2017, 2001, 2013, 2015, 2001, 2015, 2016, 2001, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2001, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2001, 
2014, 2017, 2001, 2014, 2016, 2001, 2015, 2017, 2001, 2016, 2001, 
2017, 2001, 2015, 2001, 2015, 2017, 2001, 2015, 2001, 2013, 2015, 
2017, 2001, 2009, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2006, 2007, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2001, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2015, 2016, 2001, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2013, 2014, 2001, 2013, 2014, 2016, 
2001, 2014, 2001, 2012, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2001, 2015, 2016, 2001, 
2016, 2001, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2001, 2015, 2016, 2001, 2014, 
2016, 2017, 2001, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2001, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2001, 2010, 2012, 2015, 2001, 2015, 2016, 2001, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2001, 2017), naaddressoaayn = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -183L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried the following code, however, it returns an error saying I cannot declare my year variable as a date.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(lubridate)
    library(tidyr)

df2 <- df %>%
          mutate(Year = as.Date(Year)) %>%
  complete(Year = seq.Date(min(Year), max(Year), by = "year"))
```

However it returns the following error:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(Year) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

If I remove the mutate command, as demonstrated below, then it retuns the following error:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  complete(Year = seq.Date(min(Year), max(Year), by = "year"))

Error in seq.Date(min(Year), max(Year), by = "year") : 
  'from' must be a "Date" object
```

I have also tried using the tsible package, but the fill_gaps function does not work because the observations are not recorded in regular time steps.

```
library(tsibble)

df_tsbl <-df %>%
  as_tsibble(key = State, index = Year, regular = FALSE) 

df2 <- df_tsbl %>%
  fill_gaps()

Error: Can't handle tsibble of irregular interval.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Lastly, I have tried using the padr package as well. I tried the following code:

```
library(padr)

df2 <- df_tsbl %>%
  pad(Year)

Error in pad(., Year) : object 'Year' not found

df2 <- df %>% 
   pad(interval = year, start_val = 2001, end_val = 2017)

Error: start_val should be of class Date, POSIXlt, or POSIXct

df2 <- pad(df)

Error: x contains multiple variables of class Date, POSIXct, or POSIXlt.
        Please specify which variable to use in the by argument.
```

I believe that this is a very simple problem, however, I cannot seem to find a solution for it. Please let me know what you think, I really appreciate any advice.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could share data (or part of data) that you are working on so to reproduce the error you are facing.

Comment: If `Year` is a numeric value like `2019`, you probably need something like `as.Date(paste(Year, "-01-01"))` or `lubridate::ymd(paste(year,"0101"))` to convert it to Date.

Comment: Can you share part of your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Please note that `padr` provides `pad_int` to pad years that are not in a date format.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a sequence from `min` to `max` `Year` for each `State`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(State) %>%
 tidyr::complete(Year = seq(min(Year), max(Year)))

#   State    Year naaddressoaayn
#   <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1 Alabama  2001              0
# 2 Alabama  2002             NA
# 3 Alabama  2003             NA
# 4 Alabama  2004             NA
# 5 Alabama  2005             NA
# 6 Alabama  2006             NA
# 7 Alabama  2007             NA
# 8 Alabama  2008             NA
# 9 Alabama  2009             NA
#10 Alabama  2010             NA
# … with 819 more rows
```

If we want all the states should have the same start year and end year, we can use

```
tidyr::complete(df, State, Year = seq(min(Year), max(Year)))
```